# Validate the DB2 command's output on Japenese/Chinese machine

Tags: java, windows, db2, db2-luw

The application works fine on Windows machines where DB2 is setup in English language, since need to validate the executed commands output like

```
> db2 attach to DB2 user db2admin using xxxxxx

 Instance Attachment Information

 Instance server        = DB2/NT64 10.5.1
 Authorization ID       = DB2ADMIN
 Local instance alias   = DB2
```

Actually the above output is redirected into a text file and then validated by a Java code as

```
String message = Utils.readFile(filePath);
message = message.trim().replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
String upperStr = message.toUpperCase();

if (upperStr.indexOf("INSTANCE ATTACHMENT INFORMATION") != -1
        && upperStr.indexOf("AUTHORIZATION ID") != -1)
    return "SUCCESS";
else
    return "FAILURE";
```

But the issue is: On Japanese/Chinese machine the DB2 commands generate the output in their language e.g. In Japanese Machine

```
インスタンス?Eアタッチ?﨣・インスタンス?Eサ?[バ?[ = DB2/NT 10.5.5 許可 ID = DB2ADMIN ・?[カル?Eインスタンス別名 = DB2
```

So, how to modify that language to work normally like English?
Or could the command's output be generated in English only?

Comment: Why don't you simply check the CLP return code for an error value (which is 4)? Otherwise you'd need to change the client OS language settings (vial the Regional Settings control panel or the LANG setting.

Comment: But when ATTACH command runs successfully, it doesn't return the message containing 0 (for SUCCESS). So how to handle that way?

Comment: Any OS command (including the DB2 CLP) _always_ has an exit code, which is 0 for a succesfull completion. It's not a _message_.

Comment: Ooh, then I have to understood, how to get the CLP return value in Java?


Anyway thanks for the hint.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you chose an unreliable way to determine success (or failure) of an external program. Apart from the language problem you are dealing with, there are other possible issues with trying to save and parse program output.

A better way to check the external program result is to look at its exit code. By convention, most programs (DB2 CLP included) return 0 when they end successfully and a different value if there is some sort of a problem. You can find [more information in the manual](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0010411.html?lang=en).

When executing an external program from Java, you can use  [`Process.exitValue()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue%28%29) to obtain its exit code.

Comment: I tried to get the **Process.exitValue()**

by supplying the incorrect username & password in _ATTACH_ command

**db2 attach to DB2 user db2admin2 using xxxxxx**

but still I am getting the **ZERO = 0** as the return value.

So in that case how to rely on the **returnCode**??

Comment: It's real hard to debug the code that one doesn't see, you know? Consider using  the `public Process exec(String[] cmdarray)` version.